# Supporting multiple xsd versions

Tags: java, design-patterns, xsd, jaxb

Let me explain my scenario
I have a web application that takes xml requests and responds.
I have used jaxb to parse the request, convert it to my applications dao object, process the request and then reconvert the dao result to jaxb object and return that.
Now i have to support multiple versions (different xml versions can come as request and i have to respond with suitable xml response).
I generate java files for jaxb object -> dao object convertor and reverse.
Problem is that before conversion to my dao object the jaxb object is created and then validated before passing it to my convertor. I am not sure what design pattern to apply here.
Might be adaptor pattern. Please suggest?
Also throw light if i may have to generate the jaxb marshalling and un-marshalling code too?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully I understood well your problem. So you already have:

```
xml 1 ---> jaxb objects 1 ---> converter 1 ---> entity objects
```

And now you need to acomodate a new xml format.

For this you can either write a new converter to support the new format:

```
xml 2 ---> jaxb objects 2 ---> converter 2 ---> entity objects
```

or write some xml adapters to adapt the new jaxb objects to the first format:

```
xml 2 ---> jaxb objects 2 ---> adapter ---> jaxb objects 1 ---> converter 1 ---> entity objects
```

I would suggest **the first** approach: to write a new converter so the new format is not dependent of the first one (in case might need to retire first format).

The converter mixes itself with the jaxb objects as a wrapper around the entity objects together with the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` for complex types. A very simple example:

```
public class XmlPerson {
    private Person person;

    public XmlPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public XmlPerson() {
        this.person = new Person();
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return person.getFristname();
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstName) {
        person.setFirstName(firstName);
    }

    ....

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(XmlAddressAdapter.class)
    public Address getAddress() {
        return person.getAddress();
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        person.setAddress(address);
    }
}
```

The `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` should itself adapt(convert) from an `Address` to a `XmlAddress`.

```
public class XmlAddressAdapter extends XmlAdapter<XmlAddress, Address> {
    @Override
    public Address unmarshal(XmlAddress xmlAddress) throws Exception {
        return xmlAddress.getAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public XmlAddress marshal(Address address) throws Exception {
        return address != null ? new XmlAddress(address) : null;
    }
}
```

> Also throw light if i may have to generate the jaxb marshalling and un-marshalling code too?

You just need to pass the xml objects to the marshaller and validate the `xsd` with the unmarshaller as yoou might already be doing:

Marshal:

```
   JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XmlPerson.class);
   Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
   jaxbMarshaller.marshal(xmlPerson, output);
```

Unmarshal:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(targetClass);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(
                    javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(XmlInvoice.class.getResource("/yourXsd.xsd"));
jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema);

Object unmarshalResult = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
```

Comment: Thanks dcernahoschi, I am doing similar to what you are suggesting.

Comment: I will check out the XmlJavaTypeAdapter and get back. Though too early before i check out the XmlJavaTypeAdapter, will this design work if the 2 jaxb objects are totally incompatible and mean one thing or the other

Comment: No i am not looking for something like this. To explain more. My tier architecture is xml 1 ---> jaxb objects 1 ---> some code--->converter 1 ---> entity objects
I cant modify anything in the "jaxb objects 1" java files as its generated during the war file build time using xjc. I have written a framework that can generate "convertor 1". Please suggest a design how i can make the section "some code" generic so that in future if "jaxb objects 1" changes and become incompatible with the present one, i may not have to change "some code" section.